# Junit class in spring

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am getting error on this code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContext.xml" })
```

Error:

```
file not found exception
```

Please help me.

Comment: Where is the applicationContext.xml in your project?

Comment: You can try `classpath*:applicationContext.xml` (see the `*` after classpath)... it might help.

Answer (score 2):

You should search where is applicationContext.xml located. **It must be in classpath.** I recommend you to check that it is within classes directory. If not you should or move applicationContext.xml file to the source folder that will be filtered out to the class directory or change the location in your unit-test.